# magento contact us form add multiple email ids

Tags: magento-1.9

magento contact us  form how to add multiple email id

[image]

please check this error

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add **comma** [**,**] after one email id and add as below :

**contact@example.com,contact1@example.com**

[image]

Comment: its not taking with comma

Comment: @SumaJ not taking means ? is it not saving ? please tell in detail.....

Comment: its an contact us page

Comment: @SumaJ i gave `contact@example.com,contact1@example.com` and it worked for me..... try copy this `contact@example.com,contact1@example.com` and paste in the  `field` and click on `save config` button.....

Comment: please check now

Comment: i am using magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: @SumaJ make sure you didt gave any blank spaces after email id , also try with real domain.com email id instaed of example.com , also try with gmailid once.....

Comment: i tried with real domain with no spaces.Facing same error

Comment: @SumaJ dont you see any errors if you enter only one email id ?

Comment: yes with 1 email id i am not facing any error.